# How to enable Private Google Access for Source Repositories

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking, google-source-repositories

I have Private Google Access enabled on the Default network and and I can pull artifacts from Artifact Registry from a VM with no external IP address just fine

[image]

However I can't seem to access Source Repositories though. Looking at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config), source.developers.google.com is supported so I tried adding a DNS zone for that
[image]

But no luck.

Looking at logging on the firewall rules, I can see an ALLOW when I try and git clone, but the command just hangs and eventually times out

```
git clone ssh://my.email@myorg.com@source.developers.google.com:2022/p/source-proj/r/repo1

ssh: connect to host source.developers.google.com port 2022: Connection timed out
```

There is a default route for the internet (it works for googleapis.com)

```
gcloud compute routes list \
    --filter="default-internet-gateway default"
NAME                            NETWORK  DEST_RANGE  NEXT_HOP                  PRIORITY
default-route-cb7bfa9d0dedf120  default  0.0.0.0/0   default-internet-gateway  1000
```

And there is no deny rule on Egress.

How can I set it up?

Comment: Can you connect using HTTP instead of SSH?

Comment: Yes git clone https works

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to automate \ script the 'manually generated' credentials step

Comment: The private.googleapis.com and restricted.googleapis.com VIPs support only HTTP-based protocols over TCP (HTTP, HTTPS, and HTTP/2). All other protocols, including MQTT and ICMP, are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Just sharing what @John Hanley suggested so that other user would be aware on this concern.

Regarding the connection @John Hanley mentioned to used http instead of ssh because of the limitation that can be found from this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#domain-options) that "private.googleapis.com and restricted.googleapis.com VIPs support only HTTP-based protocols over TCP (HTTP, HTTPS, and HTTP/2). All other protocols, including MQTT and ICMP, are not supported."